# Is there any way to save the Gif image to storage after merging with normal image?

Tags: android

I'm working on editing of gif image which background is transparent. For example i have one gif image works as envelope and second one is normal image works as card. Now i have to merge both so that it looks as envelope is opening and showing our card. My code is below....

```
    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/gifImageView"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Now in java file...
    GifImageView gifImageView = findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);
        Resources r = getResources();
        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.normal_card_image);
        layers[1] =r.getDrawable(R.drawable.gif_envelope_image);
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
        gifImageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

now i got the merged images in "layerDrawable" and displayed on imageView. But my question is how to save merged images(or layerDrawable) to storage? Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

```
    int width = layerDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int height = layerDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);


    File outputFile = new File("/sdcard/myNewGif.gif");
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

  if (fos != null) {
    AnimatedGifEncoder gifEncoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
    gifEncoder.start(fos);
    gifEncoder.addFrame(bitmap );
    gifEncoder.finish();
}
```

Comment: thanks But by using this code, not able to get gif format image in our storage. i'm getting blank image

Comment: if i add " layerDrawable.draw(new Canvas(bitmap)); " this line then i get normal image not gif. But i need the saved image same as displayed gif image on gifImageView.